# Running total on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, cumulative-sum

I have a table like this.

```
Date               Item               BuyItem
20150101           Mouse              10
20150101           Keyboard           100
20150202           Mouse              20
20150202           Keyboard           200
```

I want to query like this.

```
Date               Item               RunningTotal
20150101           Mouse              10
20150202           Mouse              30
20150101           Keyboard           100
20150202           Keyboard           300
```

how could i do it?
Recursive CTE is tied on one running column, like Date, right?
Now I have one running column, Date, and another grouping column Item.
help me, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Cross Apply` or `Correlated sub-query`

```
;with cte as
(
select 
 * from
 (VALUES (20150101,'Mouse',10),
               (20150101,'Keyboard',100),
               (20150202,'Mouse',20),
               (20150202,'Keyboard',200) )tc(Date, Item, BuyItem) 
)
SELECT *
FROM   cte a
       CROSS apply(SELECT Sum(BuyItem) AS running_total
                   FROM   cte b
                   WHERE  a.Item = b.Item
                          AND a.Date >= b.Date) cs
```

**Result:**

```
Date        Item        BuyItem running_total
--------    --------    ------- -------------
20150101    Mouse       10      10
20150202    Mouse       20      30
20150101    Keyboard    100     100
20150202    Keyboard    200     300
```

`Recursive CTE` method:

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY Item
                    ORDER BY date ) AS rn,*
         FROM   (VALUES (20150101,'Mouse',10),
                        (20150101,'Keyboard',100),
                        (20150202,'Mouse',20),
                        (20150202,'Keyboard',200) )tc(Date, Item, BuyItem)),
     CTE_RunningTotal
     AS (SELECT Date,Item,BuyItem,BuyItem AS running_total,rn
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  rn = 1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT T.Date,T.Item,t.BuyItem,
                T.BuyItem + C.running_total AS running_total,
                t.rn
         FROM   CTE_RunningTotal AS C
                INNER JOIN cte AS T
                        ON T.Item = c.Item
                           AND t.rn = C.rn + 1)
SELECT Date,
       Item,
       BuyItem,
       running_total
FROM   CTE_RunningTotal AS C
```

Better to update your server to `2012` which can use `sum() over(order by)` method to calculate running total which much faster than these methods

Comment: It worked with sample data. In real world data, I have Date column, two grouping columns (like item and warehouse) and Quantity Column. My table has around 20000 records. These methods take too much time and I have to stop before it gave any result.

Answer (score 1):

Make a use of windowing function. in SQL 2012+

```
DECLARE @Items TABLE
(
DATE NVARCHAR(MAX),
Item NVARCHAR(MAX),
BuyItem int
)

INSERT INTO @Items(DATE, Item, BuyItem) VALUES('20150101', 'Mouse', 10)
INSERT INTO @Items(DATE, Item, BuyItem) VALUES('20150101', 'Keyboard', 100)
INSERT INTO @Items(DATE, Item, BuyItem) VALUES('20150202', 'Mouse', 20)
INSERT INTO @Items(DATE, Item, BuyItem) VALUES('20150202', 'Keyboard', 200)

SELECT DATE, Item, SUM(BuyItem) OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY BuyItem) AS RunningTotal FROM @Items ORDER BY Item DESC
```

here is output of running above query.

```
20150101    Mouse       10
20150202    Mouse       30
20150101    Keyboard    100
20150202    Keyboard    300
```

Comment: anything less than `2012` will not allow `order by` in `Aggregate` with `window` function

Comment: @MM93 Nope above query works perfect even with SQL server 2008. look at [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf52b/2) sql fiddle.

Comment: @Jenish Rabadiya Thank! i tested on sql 2014 and it worked. But, it didn't work on sql 2008r2.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya - I guess now you believe what i said

Comment: @MM93 sorry! it does not work with actual server but works with sql fiddle. There must be something wrong with sql fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

In aggregate function, with running total, using Window functions are very good performance

In SQL 2012+:

```
SELECT *,
   SUM() OVER(PARTITION BY Item, ORDER BY Date) AS RunningTotal
FROM
Your_Table
ORDER BY Item DESC
```

Faster than when add window frame:

```
SELECT *,
   SUM() OVER(PARTITION BY Item, ORDER BY Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS RunningTotal
FROM
Your_Table
ORDER BY Item DESC
```

Comment: anything less than `2012` will not allow `order by` in `Aggregate` with `window` function

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Date,
       item,
       running_total
FROM   #yourtable a
       CROSS apply(SELECT Sum(BuyItem) AS running_total
                   FROM   #yourtable b
                   WHERE  a.Item = b.Item
                          AND a.Date >= b.Date) ca
ORDER  BY BuyItem
```